# How to find the number of edges or vertices between any two vertices of a tree?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

Its a general tree (acyclic graph), so there can be only one such path. What algorithm can I use for this?

EDIT:

Need to find the paths for all pairs of vertices in the tree

Comment: How much info you know for each node? You store its parent? The current tree level? So we can find the most efficient solution.

Comment: No, I don't store any such information. How would it help if I store such info?

Comment: I'll will write and answer assuming you know the parent of each node, doing two simple iteration without the need of recursive functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to extend @templatetypedef's answer here<sup>1</sup>.

Note that in your problem, you need to do at least one write per each pair of nodes in the tree. There are `n*(n-1)/2` of these.

Thus, in terms of big O notation, you cannot find an algorithm that runs better than `O(n^2)`.

Now, use [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to find the path per node. It will run in `O(n+m)` (`n` vertices, `m` edges). But since it is a tree, we know that `m=n-1`, giving us `O(n)` for BFS/DFS. Note that in a single BFS/DFS from some node `v` - you get `d(v,u)` for EVERY node `u`.

If you repeat it per each node, it will get you `O(n^2)` - which is optimal in terms of big O notation. I do agree you might get better constants with some optimizations, but that's about it.

---

(1) Started it as a comment, but it got too long and I figured it worth an answer.

Comment: Nice. Actually the question would have been more interesting if we were allowed to pre-process the tree, and then support individual distance queries. With this version of the problem, there's a solution of O(1) query time and only O(n) space.

Comment: @Eyal - I can pre-process the tree. What do you suggest?

Comment: @user3080029: In a nutshell, the idea is to reduce this problem to the LCA problem (Lowest Common Ancestor), which can be reduced to RMQ (Range Minimum Query). The first reduction is simple: if you know the levels of v1 and v2, and the level of their LCA node u, then d(v1,v2)=L(v1)+L(v2)-2*L(u). The second reduction is more complex, and it's described very nicely in http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor&module=Static. However, as Amit says, if you must return all distances in a collection, there's no use in this approach - Use the simple DFS approach instead.

Answer (score 0):

One simple option is to do a depth-first search starting at one of the nodes until you reach the other node. You can then look at the path that was taken from the first node to the second, which must be the unique path between those nodes, and then count how many edges are in that path. This runs in linear time because a DFS on a tree only takes linear time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Performing a DFS for each pair of vertices will be too time intensive don't you think?

Comment: @user3080029 Ah, I see that you've edited the question. It's actually not all that inefficient. Look at amit's answer for a justification why.

Answer (score 0):

You  need to find the [Lowest Common Ancestor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor) (LCA). There are different approaches as you can study here: http://leetcode.com/2011/07/lowest-common-ancestor-of-a-binary-tree-part-i.html

I have used the fallowing solution since I'm not fan to recursivity, that should work better for your problem since you need to find all the pairs in an efficient manner.

[image]

1-) Finding path between A -> B :
-Iterate starting from node A going up each parent node flagging each one with A Flag, until parent root fund.
-Iterate starting from node B going up until A Flag found. You have found LCA node.
- Result path is a list from A to LCA node, plus a reversed list from B to LCA node.

2-) Improvement finding A -> B :
- Iterate both nodes simultaneously, flagging with A Flag, and B Flag each ancestor node. Until A iterations find B Flag or B iterations find A Flag. Then the first to find another node flag has found the LCA node.

3-) Finding all pairs paths: 
 You can simply use solution above for each pair. 
 Or try to consider making a first pass iterating all the tree creating lists of flags, then a second pass to identify all LCA nodes for each pair, that would be inconvenient when the tree number of nodes grows too big.

Comment: If you choose solutions 1) or 2) you need only two fields|variables for each node to store two Flag nodes, not a list as required in solution 3).